# Can a website run a malware on my computer?

Tags: malware, webserver

Can a website install a malware on my computer and run it in the background without my knowing about it?

Comment: Even though this is closed, because of your wording "run", I just have to mention that all sites can run cryptocurrency miners in your browser without using any vulnerability. It is allowed by default. So websites don't have to "hack" your browser, they can legitimately make money of your CPU clocks and electricity as long as you have their site open. It is still being discussed, whether this is acceptable, to what extent and how to potentially prevent it.

Comment: @PeterHarmann This is quite interesting to me! can you shed a little more light on it please? is there any term for this process?

Comment: Got a nice article on this: https://qz.com/1085171/how-to-tell-if-your-computer-is-secretly-mining-cryptocurrency-and-what-to-do-about-it/